# Paging UIScrollView doesn't work :( (iPhone, cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, paging, scrollview

I found this:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9417
but the project doesn't works with iOS 4.x and cocos2d 0.99.5.

Can someone share a working project? or get it work?

Thank you very much for any help.

*PS: I will vote up any helpful answer and the one who will share a working project gets the accepted answer.*

Answer (score 1):

Hi
I don't have time (right now) but I will try to use the one you have linked and post the working project because I will be in need of this in near future.
I used http://brandonreynolds.com/blog/tag/angry-birds-menu/  once.

Edit:
If you read that topic at cocos2d forum, a person named "blackmouth" have posted a working project.
This is the link : https://github.com/blackmouth/shapes-panels

Comment: but the problme is if I create a new project (0.99.5) and then copy paste the code from the code of blackmouth it doens't work. Because I can't scroll. It's all messed up. May you try it with 0.99.5?